# Manage REST response with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I'm using Spring to create a REST api. At the moment I use this structure to provide a file explorer service:

FileModel.java

```
package hello;


    public class FileModel {
        private String name;
        private Long lastUpdate;
        private Long size;

        /**
         * Void Constructor
         */
        public FileModel() {
        }


        /**
         * Parametrized constructor
         * @param name
         * @param created
         * @param lastUpdate
         * @param size
         */
        public FileModel(String name, Long lastUpdate, Long size) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
            this.size = size;
        }


        /**
         * @return the name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        /**
         * @param name the name to set
         */
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        /**
         * @return the lastUpdate:A long value representing the time the file was last modified, 
         * measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970)
         */
        public Long getLastUpdate() {
            return lastUpdate;
        }


        /**
         * @param lastUpdate the lastUpdate to set
         */
        public void setLastUpdate(Long lastUpdate) {
            this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
        }


        /**
         * @return the size in bytes
         */
        public Long getSize() {
            return size;
        }


        /**
         * @param size the size to set
         */
        public void setSize(Long size) {
            this.size = size;
        }


    }
```

FileServices.java

```
    package hello;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    public class FileServices {

        public ArrayList<FileModel> getAllFiles(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
            ArrayList<FileModel> files=new ArrayList<FileModel>();
            File directory = new File(path);
            if (directory.exists()){
                //get all the files from a directory
                File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
                //check if list is null
                for (File file : fList){
                    if (file.isFile()){
                        FileModel f=new FileModel(file.getName(),file.lastModified(),file.length());
                        files.add(f);
                    }
                }
                return files;
            }
            else throw new ResourceNotFoundException(path);
        }
    }
```

ResourceNotFoundException.java

```
    package hello;

    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ResourceNotFoundException(String path){
            super("The specified path: "+ path +"  doesn't exist");
        }
    }
```

FileManager

```
    package hello;

    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Collection;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    @RestController
    public class FileManager {

        @Autowired
        private FileServices file;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Collection<FileModel> getAllFiles(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="/home") String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
            return file.getAllFiles(path);
        }

    }
```

The response is either error message like this

```
> {   "timestamp": 1442560477794,   "status": 404,   "error": "Not
> Found",   "exception": "hello.ResourceNotFoundException",   "message":
> "The specified path: /home  doesn't exist",   "path":
> "/MatlabLib/files" }
```

or this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "apache-tomcat-8.0.26-windows-x64.zip",
    "lastUpdate": 1441282759343,
    "size": 10470002
  },
  {
    "name": "desktop.ini",
    "lastUpdate": 1441357976196,
    "size": 282
  }
]
```

Given that I have to manage this web services through other java or matlab code, I need a custom response, for example with status, error, exception, message, body so I can check status code and undestand if there is an error or less.
    Is there in Spring a building method to do it?

Thanks

UPDATE: I created two response class, one for ErrorResponse and one for Response with different number of fied. Then I used

```
@ControllerAdvice 
public class ErrorController {

    /**
     * 
     * @param e: exception thrown
     * @return ErroreResponse
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public @ResponseBody ErrorResponse errorHandler(Exception e){   
        //Make the exception by buildErrorResponse
        return ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
    }
```

in the ErrorResponseBuilder made this method:

```
/**
 * Build exception response beginning from exception
 * @param e exception thrown
 * @return ErrorResponse: response of an exception
 */
public static ErrorResponse buildErrorResponse(Exception e){
    StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
     return new ErrorResponse(HttpStatusManager.getHttpCode(e),e.getClass().getName(),e.getMessage(),errors.toString());
}
```

and in a HttpStatusManager I implemented this:

```
public HttpStatusManager() {
    }

    /**
     * Add to this class all new exception associating a code error
     * @param exception
     * @return
     */
    public static int getHttpCode(Exception exception){
        if (exception instanceof ResourceNotFoundException);
            return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value();
        }
```

so from the controlle use this simple line

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response<Collection<FileModel>> getAllFiles(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="/home") String path) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Collection<FileModel> result;
        result = file.getAllFiles(path);
        return new Response<Collection<FileModel>>(HttpStatus.OK.value(),result);
    }
```

What do you think?

Comment: It's not a Spring thing, but I guess it may suite your needs: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.

Comment: That is already there, it is called HTTP. In the first case your http code would be 404 in the latter 200. Basically something in the 400 or 500 range indicates an error...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` which has nice API. But personally, I would rather create a custom class to handle such responses.

Of course, you need to attach to your project f.e. `Jackson JSON API` so you could build methods which returns objects. Also you have to configure `messageConverters` in your spring configuration file.

---

**UPDATE**

```
public class Response {

private Object responseBody;
private String message;
private int responseCode;
public Response() {
    responseCode = 200; //default HTTP 200 OK
}
public Object getResponseBody() {
    return responseBody;
}

public void setResponseBody(Object responseBody) {
    this.responseBody = responseBody;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public int getResponseCode() {
    return responseCode;
}

public void setResponseCode(int responseCode) {
    this.responseCode = responseCode;
}


}
```

Example of usage

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response getAllFiles(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="/home") String path) {
        Response response = new Response();
        try {
            Collection<FileModel> files = file.getAllFiles(path);
            response.setResponseBody(files);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Utils.setErrMessage(response, e);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Your `setErrMessage` function may look like this

```
public void setErrMessage(Response response, Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof NullPointerException) {
        response.setErrCode(400); //HTTP 400 Bad Request
    }
    else if(e instanceof FileNotFoundException || ...) {
        response.setErrCode(500); //HTTP 500 Interval Server Error
    }
    ...
    response.setMessage(e.getMessage);
}
```

It's just a general idea, you can change it whatever you like.

Comment: My thought is to use a new class, for example ResponeBulder, that has this fields: status, error, exception , message, body. Then with one constructor use null in body if I have an error and otherwise null in other field if I have 200 a status code. Is a good Idea? How retrieve status code, error and exception from my exceptions?

Comment: It's a very good idea (using Builder pattern would be also recommended). If I understand your problem correctly, if you're calling some method and while processing an exception would occur, why don't use just use try-catch block? You could easily extract error message, exception class etc. from Exception object in catch block and then set it to your ResponeBuilder object.

Comment: As far as error codes are concerned, you can assign them by yourself.  You could create a method like int getExceptionCode(Exception e) and based on kind of exception return a proper code. There are maybe a dozen different codes you need to distinguish.

Comment: I have to try. The body is a String variable?
Is useful to use Builder pattern instead of one class with two method()one with http and body onother with http and exception)? I upadate you as soon as I complete

Comment: Builder pattern would be a great choice, because it's elegant and in your situation you set variable number of fields (f.e. you don't set all error fields if exception doesn't occur, you don't set body when there is an exception). For a type of body element, it really depends on your needs. String may be sufficient if your service return only one thing (XML, single value, ..). But if you have more complex responses, you could create a custom class for body as well.

Comment: Of course, if you're not familiar with builder pattern you could create a regular class containing all fields: errorCode, message, body, whatever and provide setters for each. But it's not that elegant.

Comment: I post above builder code, but I have a problem because the build method take information from exception that it is null if I don't catch exception

Comment: On second thought we'd better skip builder pattern - sorry. I've updated my answer with some code samples. Let me know if that's helpful. I also apperciate upvotes/accepting answer if you feel like I've solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a generic reponse DTO and I use Spring `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` to achieve a global error handling mechanism in my rest services.

**Global Error Handler Code:**

```
@ControllerAdvice    
public class WSControllerAdvice {
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SearchControllerAdvice.class);
        @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
        public @ResponseBody WSResponse<String> errorHandler(Exception e){
            WSResponse<String> response = new WSResponse<String>();
            logger.error("Exception occured "+e.getMessage());
            response.setResponseStatus(WSResponseCode.UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION);
            response.setCount(0);
            response.getErrors().add("Unhandled Search Error : " + e.getMessage());
            return response;
        }
    }
```

**Generic Response DTO**

```
public class WSResponse<T> {

    private String responseStatus;
    private long count;
    private long totalNumFound;
    private T results ;
    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    private String nextPageMark;
    private List<Facet> facets = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

*Getter Setter removed*

You have a consistent response format with this structure in place,irrespective of the fact that an exception occurs or not.

Comment: how can I use it? So into the web server, without exception, I have to set  null value?

Comment: If you successfully served the request, your `errors` array will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

- Catch the exception and return a POJO that describes the exception details as follows:

  ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/files", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public Object getAllFiles(@RequestParam(value="path", defaultValue="/home") String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
          try{

          }catch(ResourceNotFoundException rnfEx){
             return new ExceptionDTO("ERR-001","Resource not found");
          }
      }
  ```

  where the `ExceptionDTO` represents a POJO that would transform to JSON
- Use `@ExceptionHandler` to handle the same functionality. 
  Example :  http://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-exceptionhandler-controlleradvice-handlerexceptionresolver-json-response-example